# While preparing Jam we use sugar.Why? (can you elaborate in science language)

Tags: osmosis

Actually I was trying to find out the basic necessity of adding sugar in preparing jam.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Because people like it this way. It is still good with little to no sugar but it then called a compote and not a jam and is typically eaten differently. There is not much science to talk about here! Note that sugar will also increase preservation of the jam but I am not sure this is what you are interested in. Is this a homework question? If, yes there is probably a context in which the question was asked. What is this context?

Comment: @Remi.b The sugar is actually essential to the prolonged shelf life of (especially opened) jams, which is the point of making jams in the first place.

Comment: Well... the historical interest in making jam should not be discussed here (but I am sure it was not so much your goal). I asked in my comment whether his question had to do with preservation (end of the comment). I suppose the question the OP is trying to ask is "Why adding sugar improve preservation?". The OP would need to clarify that

Comment: Someone had asked a [Q](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58210/why-doesnt-sugar-spoil) before and you'll find your answer there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology.